# equal not work in the javascript

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am using Codemirror and I want to define my own mode , I am using the function `stream.skipTo(")")` which it return `true` if the stream match `")"` if not return `undefined` ... the function work fine But I can't get the return type for this function

my code :

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("mymode", function() {

    return {
        token: function(stream,state) {

            if (stream.match("aaa") ) {
                return "style1";
            } else if (stream.match("bbb") ) {
                return "style2";
            }
                        if ( stream.match("(")) {

            stream.skipTo(")");
            var ggg=stream.skipTo(")");
           alert(ggg);

            if(ggg==="undefined")
            {
            alert("fff");
            }

              return null;
    }
            else {
                stream.next();
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

});


var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('cm'), {
    mode: "mymode",
    lineNumbers: true
});
```

Explain what code do :
if you write on editor `"("` and write any character the function  `stream.skipTo(")")` return `undefined` until you write the character `")"` it return `true` .

my problem :

when I save the return type of function in `var ggg` it saved correct But when I write the instruction `if(ggg==="undefined")` it never works.

Why the instruction `if(ggg==="undefined")` doesn't work??

[my try online](http://jsfiddle.net/TcqAf/646/)

Comment: did you try.. if (ggg === undefined) without the quotes? maybe it is not a string.

Comment: do `if(ggg===undefined)`, do not bound undefined with quote

Comment: if(ggg===undefined) it work  thanks

Comment: either: `typeof(ggg) === "undefined"`, either: `ggg === undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

`if (ggg === "undefined")` statement means you are performing strict equality check with `string` as you have bounded the `undefined` with quotes

Do 
`if(ggg === undefined)` to check with `undefined` type

---

[**`undefined`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) docs from MDN